# Drools list iteration issue

Tags: java, list, drools

```
   rule "typeChild should be unique"
when
    RuleActivator( targetMessage == "QWERTY" )
    $o:  Parent()
    $o2: ListGeneric(typeChild != null) from $o.getDetails()
$o3: ListGeneric(typeChild != null && (typeCode == $o2.typeCode)) from $o.getDetails()
then
    insert(new ValidationError(ValidationUtil.qualifyField($DECL_ROOT, $o3, "typeChild"), "UNIQUE"));end
```

I want to fire a rule if any of the typeChild in ListGenric is identical. 
Details is a list present in Parent() bean like this:

```
protected List<ListGeneric> details;
```

And also has its setters and getters.
The problem that I am getting right now is that it starts comparing form the very first item in the list and that is always the same.So, it is firing the rule each and every time. 
So, how can I insert count in it like if it compares two times then the rule should be fired??
Or if there is any other better solution to it, please recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for the existence of a second ListGeneric with a certain typeCode.

```
rule "typeChild should be unique"
when
  RuleActivator( targetMessage == "QWERTY" )
  $o:  Parent()
  $lg: ListGeneric( typeChild != null, $tc: typeCode ) from $o.getDetails()
  exists ListGeneric( typeChild != null,
                      this != $lg,
                      typeCode == $tc ) from $o.getDetails()
then
  // duplicate typeCode $tc
end
```

Note that `this != $lg` ascertains that the two ListGeneric objects are different.

There may be more than one duplicate type code, and the rule will fire, once, for each of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, that solved my issue perfectly. Sorry I lack reputation by 2 points so cannot vote ur answer up. :P